# Function hook crashes unless certain registers are used

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly, calling-convention

so I'm trying to hook a function for a game but there is one small problem. If registers such as eax, ebx, ecx, and edx are interchangeable, how come the first code sample below is crashing the game process but the second code does not crash and works as intended?

```
// Crashes game process
void __declspec(naked) HOOK_UnfreezePlayer()
{
    __asm push eax

    if ( !state->player.frozen || !state->ready )
        __asm jmp hk_Disabled

    __asm
    {
        mov eax, g_dwBase_Addr
        mov ebx, [eax + LOCAL_PLAYER_INFO_OFFSET]
        add ebx, 0x4
        mov ecx, [ebx]
        add ecx, 0x40
        lea edx, [esi + 0x0C]
        cmp edx, ecx
        je hk_Return

        hk_Disabled:
        movss [esi + 0x0C], xmm0

        hk_Return:
        pop eax
        mov ecx, g_dwBase_Addr
        add ecx, RETURN_UnfreezePlayer
        jmp ecx
    }
}

// Works
void __declspec(naked) HOOK_UnfreezePlayer()
{
    __asm push eax

    if ( !state->player.frozen || !state->ready )
        __asm jmp hk_Disabled

    __asm
    {
        mov ecx, g_dwBase_Addr
        mov edx, [ecx + LOCAL_PLAYER_INFO_OFFSET]
        add edx, 0x4
        mov ebp, [edx]
        add ebp, 0x40
        lea ecx, [esi + 0x0C]
        cmp ecx, ebp
        je hk_Return

        hk_Disabled:
        movss [esi + 0x0C], xmm0

        hk_Return:
        pop eax
        mov ecx, g_dwBase_Addr
        add ecx, RETURN_UnfreezePlayer
        jmp ecx
    }
}
```

I think the crash might be caused by my assembly code overwriting important data in the registers eax, ebx, ecx, etc.. What if the game is storing an important value in eax for example and then that data is lost because my if statement is moving a struct pointer into eax? Is there a way to preserve the contents of these registers and restore them to their original value before returning?

Comment: In the standard calling convention, only EAX, ECX, and EDX are call-clobbered.  Other registers you have to either not touch or save/restore the caller's values.  In a `naked` function, the compiler doesn't do this for you the way it normally would.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm not sure if the standard calling conventions apply here, since the OP is talking about inserting a hook into a game, probably by injecting code into it at an arbitrary location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registers are certainly not interchangable when hooking an already compiled program, as the meaning of the individual registers is defined by the code of the hooked program and the location of the hook in that code. Therefore, you must examine the hooked code and the location of the hook in order to determine whether the hooked code relies on the contents of certain registers being preserved.

With the `push eax` instruction at the start and the `pop eax` instruction at the end, you are already preserving the contents of the EAX register and restoring it afterwards. You can do the same with the EBX and EDX registers or simply use the PUSHAD/POPAD instructions to save all general-purpose registers. Depending on the location of the hook in the game, you may also have to preserve the EFLAGS register, which requires the PUSHFD/POPFD instructions.

Saving and restoring the ECX register would not be so easy, as the hook is using that register to calculate the address to jump to after it is finished.

However, since you say that the second code sample works while the first code sample causes the hooked program to crash, it is likely that the problem is only with the EBX register being modified. This is because the first code sample modifies the EBX register, whereas the second code sample does not.

Therefore, the likely solution to your problem would be to preserve the EBX register the same way as the EAX register is being preserved. In order to do so, you simply have to add a `push ebx` instruction at the same location of the `push eax` instruction and to add a `pop ebx` instruction at the same location as the `pop eax` instruction. However, please note that due to the way the stack works, the push and pop instructions must be in reverse order, like this:

Hook start:

```
push eax
push ebx
```

Hook end:

```
pop ebx
pop eax
```

Comment: Oh good point about FLAGS.  Note that `pushad` / `popad` is slower than individual push/pops, even if you did want to save all 8 (including ESP) and restore the 7 excluding ESP.

Comment: You are right. pushad / popad stopped the hook from crashing the game. I also tried push/pop eax, ecx, edx but the game still crashed so I guess other registers had to be restored as well.

Comment: @jzr448: In your previous comment, in your list of registers that you saved and restored individually (without the pushad/popad instruction), you did not mention EBX, but only EAX, ECX and EDX. As far as I can tell, EBX seems to be the most important one. Did you also try saving and restoring that one? Also, please note that the push instructions and pop instructions must be in reverse order. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm very surprised to hear that pushad/popad is slower than calling push/pop on all registers individually. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: According to [Agner Fog's testing](https://agner.org/optimize/), `popa` is 18 uops, with one per 8 cycle throughput, on Skylake.  8x `pop` is only 8 uops, and can run at 2 per clock.  `pusha`/`popa` are good for code-size but they're microcoded not very efficiently on Intel.  AMD Zen apparently does it better; `popa` there is only 9 uops, with one per 4 cycle throughput, close to the same as 8x `pop`.  Of course in real life you don't want to save/restore ESP so it's only at worst 7x push / pop that you should compare against.

Comment: Heh, turns out the OP's code only needs a single register in the hand-written asm part; updated my answer.  The C could compile to use EAX though so we might need to save/restore it if it's precious to the caller.  @jzr448.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for providing that link to Agner Fog's Optimization manuals and for the detailed information about the instruction throughput. I found it very interesting.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Other x86 performance / microarchitecture links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Agner hasn't updated for Ice Lake yet, but https://uops.info/ has.  (And their test methods are more automated and detailed than Agner's, so they're free of typos)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks also for all of these additional links. At first glance they all seem very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

> If registers such as eax, ebx, ecx, and edx are interchangeable, how come the first code sample below is crashing the game process but the second code does not crash and works as intended?

Probably your caller is using EBX for something important after this function jumps to `g_dwBase_Addr + RETURN_UnfreezePlayer`, wherever that is.

If you're hooking an existing function call, then EAX, ECX, and EDX are call-clobbered in the standard calling convention, with the other integer regs call-preserved.

It's plausible that your caller happens to not break when you destroy EBP, only when you destroy EBX.

Or if you're inserting a jump/call to this code into somewhere that wasn't expecting a function call at all, then you should save/restore every register you modify, *potentially including EFLAGS*.  (Look at the "call site" to see whether it destroys any registers after you "return"; e.g. an `add` or `cmp` only writes EFLAGS, not reads, so if you see an instruction like that you know you don't have to save/restore EFLAGS.  Similarly, `mov`'s destination is write-only.)

---

Specifically, at the top of your function before you do anything else:

```
  _asm {
      push  eax
      push  ecx
      push  edx
      // and whatever other register you need
  }
```

and at the bottom, pop them in matching order before jumping

```
  _asm {
      // and whatever other register you need
      pop   edx
      pop   ecx
      pop   eax
      jmp   target
  }
```

You're using a register to hold a jump target.  You might be able to analyze the "caller" and find a register that's safe to destroy, so you can use that one without/save restore.  Or hard-code the jump target address so you can use a `jmp rel32` instead of an indirect `jmp reg`.

Or (at significant performance cost) you can replace `jmp` with `push` / `ret`.

```
  _asm {
     push eax    // extra dummy slot we can replace with a return address
     push eax
     push ecx
     push edx

  ...

     pop  edx
     pop  ecx
     //pop  eax

     mov  eax, g_dwBase_Addr
     add  eax, RETURN_UnfreezePlayer
     mov  [esp+4], eax       // store into the dummy slot
     pop  eax
     ret                     // branch mispredict guaranteed
  }
```

Using the equivalent of push/ret guarantees a branch mispredict for this ret, and for future `ret` instructions up the call stack because we got the call/ret predictor stack mismatched.  A dummy `call` somewhere in this function could fix that, making just *this* `ret` mispredict.  (But note that `call next_instruction`  won't work; CPUs special case that and don't treat it as a real call.  You have to actually jump over something.  http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/#call0)

You might be tempted to `xchg [esp], eax` / `ret`, but that's *very* slow: xchg with a memory operand implies a `lock` prefix (full memory barrier, microcoded atomic exchange).

Reserving a slot for a "return address" when initially pushing seems most efficient, otherwise you might push a return address, `mov` load the saved EAX value, then `pop [esp+4]` to copy that return address up by 4 bytes.  But that extra copy will add latency before the `ret` mispredict can be discovered.

**If this doesn't have to be thread safe, you could use `jmp [target_address]` after storing a target address**.  Or if `g_dwBase_Addr + RETURN_UnfreezePlayer` is a constant, just keep that in a static variable somewhere so you can `jmp dword ptr [target_address]` instead of computing the target every time.

You *could* use space below ESP, but that's not strictly safe. Like `jmp [esp-4]` after restoring registers.  SEH could step on it, and so could a debugger.

---

## you can optimize your function to use fewer registers

Specifically, you only need to modify one, so you can just save/restore it.  Or none at all if you pick one you can safely clobber for the return address.

After these two instructions, you never use EAX again.

```
mov eax, g_dwBase_Addr
mov ebx, [eax + LOCAL_PLAYER_INFO_OFFSET]
```

So you could use EAX instead of EBX:

```
mov eax, g_dwBase_Addr
mov eax, [eax + LOCAL_PLAYER_INFO_OFFSET]
; then use EAX everywhere you were using EBX in later instructions
```

So that's fewer registers to save/restore.  Also, this is pointless:

```
    add ebx, 0x4         ;  add eax, 4        // with changes from above
    mov ecx, [ebx]       ;  mov ecx, [eax]
```

can do the `+4` in the addressing mode: **`mov ecx, [eax + 4]`**

The add/lea -> `cmp` can also be optimized.  `ecx + 0x40 == esi + 0xc` is the same thing as `ecx + 0x40 - 0xc == esi`.

```
    // no push or pop needed, destroying only ECX
    _asm {
        mov ecx, g_dwBase_Addr
        mov ecx, [ecx + LOCAL_PLAYER_INFO_OFFSET]
        mov ecx, [ecx+4]

        add ecx, 0x40 - 0x0C
        cmp ecx, esi               // ecx+0x40 == esi+0x0C
        je hk_Return

        hk_Disabled:
        movss [esi + 0x0C], xmm0    // regs from the caller

        hk_Return:
          // Assuming we can destroy caller's ECX.
        mov ecx, g_dwBase_Addr
        add ecx, RETURN_UnfreezePlayer
        jmp ecx
    }
```